# Bash Command Substitution with variable with "find"

Tags: bash

Goal: get all mp4 names in a directory and store them in a variable.
I want to get the output of `find` command with some variables(arguments passed in)

```sh
dir='.'
search="-iname '*.mp4'"

find . -iname '*.mp4'             # works but need to use variable instead of hard code

find $dir $search                 # failed
output=$(find $. "$search")       # failed
...                               # all failed
```

Comment: Why do you need `-iname` as part of your `search` variable? Why not `search="*.mp4"` then `find $dir -iname $search`, and `output=$(find $dir -iname $search)`? The problem is that `"-iname '*.mp4"` will be treated as a single string argument to `find` if you use `search="-iname '*.mp4'`.

Comment: I tried this just now, but it didn't work for me, either.

Comment: We'll you need to show exactly what you did. I tried it and it worked fine for me.

Comment: You are most likely seeing different results based on whether or not you have any `.mp4` files in the current directory. If you do, it'll fail with an error or find too few matches. If you don't, it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: The first method doesn't work in all cases, use the second one.

The single quotes around your `'*mp4'` mean you're searching for a file name with single quotes around it. Remove them and it works:

```sh
dir="."
search="-iname *.mp4"
find "$dir" $search
```

Another way to do it, which would allow spaces in your search strings and prevent other [pitfalls from not using quoted variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), is to use arrays for your additional arguments:

```sh
dir="."
args=("-iname" "*.mp4")
find "$dir" "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you! the first method didn't work for me, but the second one works.

Comment: The first method fails if you have `mp4` files in the current directory, or if either the nullglob or failglob options are set. The second way always works, and it's therefore preferable